# Why doesn't my slider move?

Tags: javascript, html, slider

So I have an input in HTML of type "range", which is a slider that allows you to move small box to the left or to the right. When I move that slider I want to change an angle in my code. But when I drag the box it doesn't move.

Here is the HTML for the slider:

```html
<div id="slider">
        <form>
            <input type="range" id="scale" value="6" min="4" max="8" step="1">
        </form>
    </div>
```

The strange thing is that when I make a new page only with the slider and nothing else it moves.

Here is the JavaScript for modifying my angle:

```js
function rederer(angle) {
  angle = document.getElementById("scale").value * 10;
  if (slice_one.rotation.y <= Math.PI / 2) {
    slice_one.rotation.y += Math.PI / angle;
  }
  if (slice_four.rotation.y >= -Math.PI * 0.5) {
    slice_four.rotation.y -= Math.PI / angle;
  }
  if (group_1_2.rotation.y >= -Math.PI * 0.2) {
    group_1_2.rotation.y -= Math.PI * angle;
  }

  if (group_3_4.rotation.y <= Math.PI / 3) {
    group_3_4.rotation.y += Math.PI / angle;
  }
  stats.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
document.getElementById("scale").onchange = function() {
  var angle = this.value * 10;
  rederer(angle);
}
```

Can somebody tell me why does it work when I put it in an empty HTML page but it doesn't move when I put it inside my code?

[Here you can see how that slider looks like](http://jsfiddle.net/kgqvu6bs/)

**NOTE** The idea behind my whole code is the following: I have a number of slices from a picture, which I store using the '2d' context of canvas. I'm using three.js library to achieve a 3d folding effect (like you fold a paper/flyer). The role of that slider is to increase/decrease the angle of the foldings

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jslint.com/

it looks like there's a additional } tag, try removing it, **NOTE** this won't fix the error you described, but will at least allow you to continue to troubleshoot the issue (slice_one is not defined)

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. I just made a mistake when I copy/pasted my code here. :)

Comment: Everything is defined there. My code is much larger, but it would be pointless to just put here 400 lines of code.